# How can I build an sqlite table from this xml/txt file using python?

Tags: python, mysql, xml, sqlite

I have an xml/txt file like this:

```
<text id="32a45" language="ENG" date="2017-01-01" time="11:00" timezone="Eastern">

<s id="1">
foo
bar
</s>
<d>
11235
</d>

<text id="32a47" language="ENG" date="2017-01-05" time="1:00" timezone="Central">

<s id="2">
foo
bar
</s>
<d>
11235
</d>

<text id="32a48" language="ENG" date="2017-01-07" time="3:00" timezone="Pacific">

<s id="3">
foo
bar
</s>
<d>
11235
</d>
```

I want to build an sqlite table like the following using python:

```
id  language    date        timezone    s           d

32a45   ENG     2017-01-01  Eastern     foo bar     11235
32a47   ENG     2017-01-05  Central     baz qux     11235
32a48   ENG     2017-01-07  Pacific     foo bar     11235
```

Any idea how can I do this? I cannot use xmltree module because the xml tags in the original file is messed up. I would really appreciate the help. Thanks.

Edit: I can easily take each text as a list inside a list. Like this:

```
['<text id="32a45" language="ENG" date="2017-01-01" time="11:00" timezone="Eastern">', '<text id="32a47" language="ENG" date="2017-01-05" time="1:00" timezone="Central">', '<text id="32a48" language="ENG" date="2017-01-07" time="3:00" timezone="Pacific">']
```

But I don't know how to take the id, language etc. from each list separately.

Comment: Any particular reason why you're tagging R in this?

Comment: Yes. If there is a built in library to do this in R, that would work for me as well. I know there is a RSQlite package in R. However, I have not used it before. That being said, I don't think R can be any more useful here than python. Just keeping an option open.

Comment: Is this about parsing XML or about putting something into SQLite? Seems like those are two separate problems, and simple enough that they've been answered individually multiple times on SO. (For instance, the first google hit searching "python xml parse" brings up [python2 help on the `xml` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), rife with example data and code.)

Comment: It is mainly about putting something in sqlite. And I cannot use xmltree in this case because of some tagging issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirected from here:

[How can I make sublists from a list based on strings in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45541933/how-can-i-make-sublists-from-a-list-based-on-strings-in-python/45542075?noredirect=1#comment78045395_45542075)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

strings = ['<text id="32a45" language="ENG" date="2017-01-01" time="11:00" timezone="Eastern">',
'<text id="32a47" language="ENG" date="2017-01-05" time="1:00" timezone="Central">',
'<text id="32a48" language="ENG" date="2017-01-07" time="3:00" timezone="Pacific">']

cols = ["id","language","date","time","timezone"]
data = [[ET.fromstring(string+"</text>").get(col) for col in cols] for string in strings]    
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=cols)
```