# How can I make sublists from a list based on strings in python?

Tags: python, string, list, sublist

I have a list like this:

```
['<text id="32a45" language="ENG" date="2017-01-01" time="11:00" timezone="Eastern">',
'<text id="32a47" language="ENG" date="2017-01-05" time="1:00" timezone="Central">',
'<text id="32a48" language="ENG" date="2017-01-07" time="3:00" timezone="Pacific">']
```

From this I want to make sublists like:

```
id = ["32a45", "32a47", "32a48"]
date=["2017-01-01", "2017-01-05", "2017-01-07"]
```

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Edit: This was the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45540531/how-can-i-build-an-sqlite-table-from-this-xml-txt-file-using-python?noredirect=1#comment78041733_45540531)
It is a broken xml file and tags are messed up, hence I cannot use xmltree. So I am trying something else.

Comment: And how do you get that file (looks like broken xml/html)

Comment: With regex or parse xml, have you tried anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple solution using `re.search()` function:

```
import re

l = ['<text id="32a45" language="ENG" date="2017-01-01" time="11:00" timezone="Eastern">',
'<text id="32a47" language="ENG" date="2017-01-05" time="1:00" timezone="Central">',
'<text id="32a48" language="ENG" date="2017-01-07" time="3:00" timezone="Pacific">']

ids, dates = [], []
for i in l:
    ids.append(re.search(r'id="([^"]+)"', i).group(1))
    dates.append(re.search(r'date="([^"]+)"', i).group(1))

print(ids)    # ['32a45', '32a47', '32a48']
print(dates)  # ['2017-01-01', '2017-01-05', '2017-01-07']
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing with ET:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
strings = ['<text id="32a45" language="ENG" date="2017-01-01" time="11:00" timezone="Eastern">',
'<text id="32a47" language="ENG" date="2017-01-05" time="1:00" timezone="Central">',
'<text id="32a48" language="ENG" date="2017-01-07" time="3:00" timezone="Pacific">']

id_ = []
date = []
for string in strings:
    tree = ET.fromstring(string+"</text>") #corrects wrong format
    id_.append(tree.get("id"))
    date.append(tree.get("date"))

print(id_) #  ['32a45', '32a47', '32a48']
print(date) # ['2017-01-01', '2017-01-05', '2017-01-07']
```

**Update, full compact example**:
According to your original problem described here: [How can I build an sqlite table from this xml/txt file using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45540531/how-can-i-build-an-sqlite-table-from-this-xml-txt-file-using-python?noredirect=1#comment78041733_45540531)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

strings = ['<text id="32a45" language="ENG" date="2017-01-01" time="11:00" timezone="Eastern">',
'<text id="32a47" language="ENG" date="2017-01-05" time="1:00" timezone="Central">',
'<text id="32a48" language="ENG" date="2017-01-07" time="3:00" timezone="Pacific">']

cols = ["id","language","date","time","timezone"]
data = [[ET.fromstring(string+"</text>").get(col) for col in cols] for string in strings]    
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=cols)

    id  language    date    time    timezone
0   32a45   ENG     2017-01-01  11:00   Eastern
1   32a47   ENG     2017-01-05  1:00    Central
2   32a48   ENG     2017-01-07  3:00    Pacific
```

Now you can use:
df.to_sql()

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

Answer (score 0):

```
id = [i.split(' ')[1].split('=')[1].strip('"') for i in list]
date = [i.split(' ')[3].split('=')[1].strip('"') for i in list]
```

But the file looks strange, if the original file is html or xml, there are better ways to get data.

Comment: It is a broken xml file. I wish I could use xmltree on it. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @AntonvBR Yes. That's after building the list. The original file looks something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45540531/how-can-i-build-an-sqlite-table-from-this-xml-txt-file-using-python?noredirect=1#comment78041733_45540531
That's my primary goal. If you can help with that, that would be awesome. Thanks again :)

Comment: @0x1 Well seeing you extracted the thing already, have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: @AntonvBR That's great! Would you post your updated answer to the original question so that I can mark that as the correct answer?

Comment: @0x1 No worries, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

As your provided data appears to be broken/partial xml fragments I would personally try repairing the xml and using the `xml.etree` module to extract the data. However if you have correct xml that you have got your current list from, then it would be easier to use the `xml.etree` module on that data.

An example solution using `xml.etree`:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

data = ['<text id="32a45" language="ENG" date="2017-01-01" time="11:00" timezone="Eastern">',
'<text id="32a47" language="ENG" date="2017-01-05" time="1:00" timezone="Central">',
'<text id="32a48" language="ENG" date="2017-01-07" time="3:00" timezone="Pacific">']

ids = []
dates = []
for element in data:
    #This wraps the element in a root tag and gives it a closing tag to
    #  repair the xml to a valid format.
    root = ET.fromstring('{}</text>'.format(element))

    #As we have formatted the xml ourselves we can guarantee that it's first
    #  child will always be the desired element.
    ids.append(root.attrib['id'])
    dates.append(root.attrib['date'])

print(ids)    # ['32a45', '32a47', '32a48']
print(dates)  # ['2017-01-01', '2017-01-05', '2017-01-07']
```

Comment: You can remove <root> (ok you just did.. but now it is a copy of what I wrote?)

Comment: Yeah, I was mid-writing mine when yours came up. So we do kind of have duplicate answers, and yours was the reason I simplified by removing the `<root>` element.

Comment: No worries, happens all the time when you write answers. People are so quick.

Answer (score 0):

Along with other answers who are better you can parse the data manually (more simple):

```
for line in lines:
    id = line[line.index('"')+1:]
    line = id
    line = id[line.index('"')+1:]
    id = id[:id.index('"')]
    print('id: ' + id)
```

You can then simply push it in the new list, repeat the same process for other values below simply change the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Not as elegant as @RomanPerekhrest solution using `re` but here it goes:

```
def extract(lst, kwd):
   out = []
   for t in lst:
       index1 = t.index(kwd) + len(kwd) + 1
       index2 = index1 + t[index1:].index('"') + 1
       index3 = index2 + t[index2:].index('"')
       out.append(t[index2:index3])
   return out
```

Then

```
>>> extract(lst, kwd='id')
['32a45', '32a47', '32a48']
```

Answer (score 0):

More easier way to understand with `re` module:
Here is the code :

```
l = ['<text id="32a45" language="ENG" date="2017-01-01" time="11:00" timezone="Eastern">', 
'<text id="32a47" language="ENG" date="2017-01-05" time="1:00" timezone="Central">',
 '<text id="32a48" language="ENG" date="2017-01-07" time="3:00" timezone="Pacific">']

import re
id =[]
dates= []
for i in l:
    id.append(re.search(r'id="(.+?)"',i, re.M|re.I).group(1))
    dates.append(re.search(r'date="(.+?)"',item, re.M|re.I).group(1))
```

Output:

```
print id     #id= ['32a45', '32a47', '32a48']
print dates  #dates= ['2017-01-07', '2017-01-07', '2017-01-07']
```